# http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/labs/labs/jbossrules/trunk/drools-api/src/main/resources/change-set-1.0.0.xsd returning 301

Tags: java, jboss, drools, drools-guvnor

My application is running on java 7/ jboss 5.2.
I am using drools 5.3 and loading my rules from guvnor 5.3.

Starting this morning I am getting an error loading a ChangeSet from guvnor, confirmed the application was working fine yesterday.

The changeset XML is loading fine but I believe the schema validator is trying to load the schema.  Which has the XSD URL http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/labs/labs/jbossrules/trunk/drools-api/src/main/resources/change-set-1.0.0.xsd.

This URL is returning a 301 status code and Location header of 
Location: https://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/labs/labs/jbossrules/trunk/drools-api/src/main/resources/change-set-1.0.0.xsd.

The https url load fine in a browser but I believe the code is ignoring the redirect and trying to load the XSD from the response and throwing a org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file as the response body is blank.

I was able to work around the problem using -Ddrools.schema.validating=false but I could not find much documentation on this option and what it is doing.

Is there a way to get the XML parser to follow the redirect or a change I can make to guvnor to use the correct XSD?

Stack Trace:

```
10:28:16,573 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to parse ChangeSet
10:28:16,574 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.drools.agent.impl.KnowledgeAgentImpl.getChangeSet(KnowledgeAgentImpl.java:432)
10:28:16,574 ERROR [STDERR]      at XXX.interactive.rules.RuleAgentManagerGuiImpl.createKnowledgeAgent(RuleAgentManagerGuiImpl.java:192)
10:28:16,574 ERROR [STDERR]      at XXX.interactive.rules.RuleAgentManagerGuiImpl.init(RuleAgentManagerGuiImpl.java:131)
10:28:16,574 ERROR [STDERR]      at XXX.RuleAgentManagerGuiImpl.initialize(RuleAgentManagerGuiImpl.java:70)
10:28:16,574 ERROR [STDERR]      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
10:28:16,574 ERROR [STDERR]      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
10:28:16,574 ERROR [STDERR]      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
10:28:16,574 ERROR [STDERR]      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
10:28:16,574 ERROR [STDERR]      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
10:28:16,574 ERROR [STDERR]      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
10:28:16,574 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:344)
10:28:16,574 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:295)
10:28:16,574 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:130)
10:28:16,574 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:396)
10:28:16,574 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1507)
10:28:16,574 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
10:28:16,574 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
10:28:16,574 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
10:28:16,574 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
10:28:16,574 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
10:28:16,574 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
10:28:16,574 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:638)
10:28:16,575 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942)
10:28:16,575 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.__refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
10:28:16,575 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java)
10:28:16,575 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
10:28:16,575 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
10:28:16,575 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
10:28:16,575 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3910)
10:28:16,575 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4389)
10:28:16,575 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:313)
10:28:16,575 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:145)
10:28:16,575 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
10:28:16,575 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:122)
10:28:16,575 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
10:28:16,575 ERROR [STDERR]      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
10:28:16,575 ERROR [STDERR]      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
10:28:16,575 ERROR [STDERR]      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
10:28:16,575 ERROR [STDERR]      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
10:28:16,575 ERROR [STDERR]      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
10:28:16,575 ERROR [STDERR]      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
10:28:16,575 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
10:28:16,575 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
10:28:16,575 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
10:28:16,575 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
10:28:16,575 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
10:28:16,575 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
10:28:16,575 ERROR [STDERR]      at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.start(Unknown Source)
10:28:16,575 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
10:28:16,575 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
10:28:16,576 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
10:28:16,576 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
10:28:16,576 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
10:28:16,576 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
10:28:16,576 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:297)
10:28:16,576 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
10:28:16,576 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
10:28:16,576 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
10:28:16,576 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
10:28:16,576 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
10:28:16,576 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
10:28:16,576 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
10:28:16,576 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
10:28:16,576 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
10:28:16,576 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
10:28:16,576 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
10:28:16,576 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
10:28:16,576 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55)
10:28:16,576 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
10:28:16,576 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1454)
10:28:16,576 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1172)
10:28:16,576 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1193)
10:28:16,576 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1225)
10:28:16,576 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1113)
10:28:16,576 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
10:28:16,576 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
10:28:16,576 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
10:28:16,577 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
10:28:16,577 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
10:28:16,577 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
10:28:16,577 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
10:28:16,577 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:789)
10:28:16,577 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:699)
10:28:16,577 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
10:28:16,577 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
10:28:16,577 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
10:28:16,577 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:403)
10:28:16,577 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
10:28:16,577 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
10:28:16,577 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
10:28:16,577 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
10:28:16,577 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
10:28:16,577 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:778)
10:28:16,577 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:543)
10:28:16,577 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.registerProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:308)
10:28:16,577 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:256)
10:28:16,577 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
10:28:16,577 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:229)
10:28:16,577 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.Main$1.call(Main.java:561)
10:28:16,577 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.jboss.Main$1.call(Main.java:557)
10:28:16,577 ERROR [STDERR]      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
10:28:16,577 ERROR [STDERR]      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
10:28:16,577 ERROR [STDERR]      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
10:28:16,578 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
10:28:16,578 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
10:28:16,578 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
10:28:16,578 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
10:28:16,578 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
10:28:16,578 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
10:28:16,578 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
10:28:16,578 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(Unknown Source)
10:28:16,578 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(Unknown Source)
10:28:16,578 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
10:28:16,578 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(Unknown Source)
10:28:16,578 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
10:28:16,579 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(Unknown Source)
10:28:16,579 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(Unknown Source)
10:28:16,579 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
10:28:16,579 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
10:28:16,579 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
10:28:16,579 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
10:28:16,579 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
10:28:16,579 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
10:28:16,579 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
10:28:16,579 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
10:28:16,579 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
10:28:16,579 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
10:28:16,579 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
10:28:16,579 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
10:28:16,579 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.drools.xml.ExtensibleXmlParser.read(ExtensibleXmlParser.java:293)
10:28:16,579 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.drools.xml.ExtensibleXmlParser.read(ExtensibleXmlParser.java:172)
10:28:16,579 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.drools.xml.XmlChangeSetReader.read(XmlChangeSetReader.java:65)
10:28:16,579 ERROR [STDERR]      at org.drools.agent.impl.KnowledgeAgentImpl.getChangeSet(KnowledgeAgentImpl.java:430)
10:28:16,579 ERROR [STDERR]      ... 102 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reply I got from redhat support was:

"
The change was intentional, for security reasons.

Workarounds for code that doesn't understand redirects:
- change the xsd reference from http to https
- disable xsd validation (code specific, I believe Drools has a system property to do this)
"

I disabled the validation.  I have not found a way to update guvnor to change the XSD within the XML it produces, I did not really try to find it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment so I'll have to put it in an answer.

We had the same exception with our reference to the schema being in a Spring XML configuration file. It seems the underlying Java stream reading the file is unable to follow the redirect. Our solution was simply to use HTTPS instead of HTTP in the XSD URL thus avoiding the redirect.

It made me aware that relying on external resources like this for a production application should maybe be reevaluated.

Comment: Me too, had no idea my application was relying on it until it stopped working.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a configuration or version change that would allow it to follow the redirect, it seems like a very common behavior.